# Storing validated data extracted from text file into variable

Tags: arrays, vba, text-files

I'm trying to store specific lines from a text file into a variable first validating each line and then splitting each valid line into columns in a bi-dimensional dynamic array . I have this code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub GetMaterialFromText()
Dim Delimiter As String
Dim TextFile As Integer
Dim FilePath As String
Dim FileContent As String
Dim LineArray() As String
Dim DataArray() As String
Dim TempArray() As String
Dim Rw As Integer, Cl As Integer, x As Integer, y As Integer
'inputs
Delimiter = ":"
FilePath = "C:\Users\jlopez\Desktop\2018\material.txt"
Rw = 0
'open the text file in a read state
TextFile = FreeFile
Open FilePath For Input As TextFile
'store file content iside a variable
 FileContent = Input(LOF(TextFile), TextFile)
 'close text file
Close TextFile
'separate out lines of data
LineArray() = Split(FileContent, vbCrLf)

'read data into an array variable
For x = LBound(LineArray) To UBound(LineArray)
If Module1.TEXTCOUNTER(LineArray(x), ":") >= 30 Then
'split up line of text by delimiter
TempArray = Split(LineArray(x), Delimiter)
'determine how many columns are needed
Cl = UBound(TempArray)
're-adjust array bundaries
ReDim Preserve DataArray(Rw, Cl)  '<-- here is the alert of Run-Time Error 9
'load line of data into array variable
For y = LBound(TempArray) To UBound(TempArray)
DataArray(Rw, y) = TempArray(y)
Next y
End If
'new line
Rw = Rw + 1
Next x

End Sub
```

UDF TEXTCOUNTER code is this:

```
Function TEXTCOUNTER(Text As String, ToCount As String) As Integer
Application.Volatile
With Application.WorksheetFunction
TEXTCOUNTER = Len(Text) - Len(.Substitute(Text, ToCount, ""))
End With
End Function
```

but I received a Run-Time error '9', I think it's caused by the dynamic arrays but I don't know how to make it run correctly, can somebody help me?

Comment: Where does the error occur? We need more information. Have you tried debugging it yourself yet?

Comment: Error occurs in this line:
**Preserve DataArray(Rw, Cl)  '<-- here is the alert of Run-Time Error 9**
and yes,. I did try to solve this but I also cannot reach it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with redim preserve, since it can only change the bounds of the last dimension, not the first, see [redim - VBA language reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg251578.aspx).

The other problem you may have later if the number of elements within a row is different row by row and you resize the upper bound of the 2nd dimension of the actual row to a number, that is less than the element count in the previous rows, since you will drop values.

I would use a 1 dimansional dynamic array to host the data, where each element would be a dynamic array itself.

```
Dim DataArray()
...
ReDim DataArray(Ubound(LineArray))

For x = LBound(LineArray) To UBound(LineArray)
  If Module1.TEXTCOUNTER(LineArray(x), ":") >= 30 Then
    'split up line of text by delimiter
    DataArray(x) = Split(LineArray(x), Delimiter)
  End If
Next x
```

To access an element use DataArray(x)(y) syntax, not DataArray(x,y).